# Lambda function returning headers and statuscode as json nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working with a NodeJS Lambda function and when I invoke it I get this as the result:

```
{
  "body": "{\"message\":\"Hello from Lambda!\"}"
}
```

It seems as if the response is not being parsed correctly, because according to what I've seen the response should just be the hello world string. This is the code I have with the function.

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  // TODO implement
  const response = {
      body: JSON.stringify({
          message: "Hello from Lambda!",
      }),
  };

  return response;
};
```

Which is the default code AWS gives you when creating a function. Does anyone know what might be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value is exactly what you return. If you just want to return "Hello from Lambda" then your function should be:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
  return "Hello from Lambda!";
};
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm just starting out with Lambda so thank you very much!

Comment: @DanielMedina No problem. Glad it worked out:-)